# Going through a DataFrame using .iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I want to do is save part of the dataframe into a list.
I have my DataFrame data_S and when it is printed it looks like this:

data_S

```
       open     high       low   close      volume      datetime
0    329.30  334.860  327.8800  333.74   5357973.0  1.578290e+12
1    334.26  344.190  330.7100  337.28   9942277.0  1.578377e+12
2    332.40  334.030  329.6000  331.37   8246250.0  1.578463e+12
3    334.95  341.730  332.0500  336.34   8183707.0  1.578550e+12
4    335.56  337.700  329.4548  329.92   7170124.0  1.578636e+12
..      ...      ...       ...     ...         ...           ...
249  216.36  218.554  214.3650  216.67  10812617.0  1.609308e+12
250  216.24  216.900  212.7000  214.06  10487567.0  1.609394e+12
251  210.00  210.200  202.4911  202.72  21225594.0  1.609740e+12
252  204.74  213.350  204.6000  211.63  19338304.0  1.609826e+12
253  210.22  215.610  209.3400  211.03  16202157.0  1.609913e+12
```

I want to be able to replicate the code below and change the value of the bolded with a for loop value of nums.

```
list_of_five_day_range = []
#so then it starts with the first list being the most recent and then in
#[X,Y,Z] Z is the most recent high or is in data_S[253]['high']
list_of_max_value = []
bars = data_S.iloc[-**5**:]['high']
list_of_five_day_range.append(list(bars))
max_value = bars.max()
list_of_max_value.append(max_value)    

bars1 = data_S.iloc[**-6:-1**]['high']
list_of_five_day_range.append(list(bars1))
max_value1 = bars1.max()
list_of_max_value.append(max_value1)

max_id = bars.max()

# [X,Y,Z] Z is the most recent with the list at [0] is the most recent data
print(str(list_of_five_day_range) + " this is last 5 days of data")

# with the first number in the list is for the most recent first day high.
print(str(list_of_max_value)+" this is maxium number in last 5 days")
```

returns

```
[[218.554, 216.9, 210.2, 213.35, 215.61], [221.68, 218.554, 216.9, 210.2, 213.35]] this is last 5 days of data
[218.554, 221.68] this is maxium number in last 5 days
```

but in a function and for it to go through the DataFrame. This is what I have so far

```
def five_day_range(price_history):

    for nums in range(len(price_history.index) - 1):
        list_of_five_day_range = []
        #so then it starts with the first list being the most recent and then [X,Y,Z] Z is the most recent
        list_of_max_value = []
        bars = price_history.iloc[-5 + int(-nums): int(-nums)]["high"]
        list_of_five_day_range.append(bars)
        max_value = bars.max()
        list_of_max_value.append(max_value)
        # print( str(bars)+ " this is the veyr first list of range ")


    return list_of_five_day_range, list_of_max_value
```

However, when I `print(five_day_range(data_S))` this is what I get

```
([0    334.86
1    344.19
Name: high, dtype: float64], [344.19])
```

I dont understand why it is printing this when the nums value should be going up the DataFrame. This is how I thought the for loop would go through the DataFrame.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRxf7.png)

I thought it would first append the yellow data then the blue and green, and so on until it hits index[0]/

Comment: Can you explain what you want to get done. It is kind of difficult to figure out what you are planning to do in the code. Just explain in plain english. There may be better ways to get this done. Also try to use 10 to 15 rows of data to explain the problem. You have 10 rows displayed and your iloc position is 250+ so we dont know what you are doing. Looks like you are iterating backwards and finding out if open is greater than close value

Comment: This is not a specific on-topic question about programming, please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You can answers most of these questions yourself just with `print`. Wherever you got this code from, it's really bad pandas idiom, I recommend not using it, esp. the gap-counting. The for-loop doesn't throw error simply because the accesses with `.iloc[]` to the dataframe rows are hardcoded to indices 250, 251, 254, 260 which presumably are hardcoded to this dataset. `.apply()` is better idiom. Also, you need to show rows 249..260

Comment: Hi I hope the way that I rephrased the questions explains what I want to be accomplished better. Please let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: Hi I just reworded my answer again and I went through the guidelines and I made the necessary changes. How is the question now?

Comment: Can you please post what your expected output is. That will help everyone and clarify what you are trying to do. You maybe able to use apply() to get what you want or there may be other ways.

Comment: @svlad4560, can you share in clear text mode, input data, expected output. That will help everyone understand what you want to get done. Otherwise, this post will stay open as unclear and eventually will get closed. I strongly recommend sharing input and expected output data to help us get to the answer

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

I believe `data_S.drop(columns=['high', 'low'])` returns another dataframe, which by default requires you to reassign the result into another variable.

With that in mind, you can either do:

`data_S = data_S.drop(columns=["high", "low"])`

or

`data_S.drop(columns=["high", "low"], inplace=True)`

**UPDATED based on updated question**:

Try this, and your list should be returned as expected.
You are defining list_of_five_day_range and list_of_max_value as [] on every iteration of the loop. Hope that makes sense.

```
def five_day_range(price_history):
    list_of_five_day_range = []
    list_of_max_value = []
    for nums in range(len(price_history.index) - 1):
        bars = price_history.iloc[-5 + int(-nums): int(-nums)]["high"]
        list_of_five_day_range.append(bars)
        max_value = bars.max()
        list_of_max_value.append(max_value)

    return list_of_five_day_range, list_of_max_value
```

Comment: thank you so much and for the way you answered! Helped me understand much better

Comment: the biggest issue is that I don't want to go down it side by side I want the values to be staggered.

Comment: no worries, do you mind editing your question to show what you are expecting the output to look like? using a csv or something? It is a little hard to visualize what you are going for :)

Comment: I have not replicated the code myself yet, but just looking at your edited question, noticed that you are defining:
list_of_five_day_range = []
max_value = []

on every iteration of the loop. So this list gets "reset" every time. Why not try defining these 2 empty lists outside of your for-loop?

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and I understand the logic behind it!